# How can I build a local JavaSE build that uses CEF and not JavaFX?

Tags: codenameone

In the Simulator, CEF is correctly used, but I noticed that local `JavaSE` builds use `JavaFX`. Can `CEF` be used in local `JavaSE` builds?

My main Stub class already contains the following:

```
Class.forName("org.cef.CefApp");
System.setProperty("cn1.javase.implementation", "cef");
```

But (when running the resulting jar on windows) JavaFX seems to be picked by the build. Do I need to copy the cef folder to the target javaSE output? I tried doing this but it also didn't work

If I run the resulting jar with `java -jar`, the CEF output that is seen when running the simulator (copied below) isn't printed in the console

`Adding CEF to classpath...`

Has CEF been excluded from local JavaSE builds explicitly? If so, it would be great if there could be a build hint to force the resulting build to look for cef libs in the `/lib` directory

Answer (score 1):

Not so much excluded as not added. We need to add some support for that. You would also need to place the right DLLs in the right path for this to ultimately work. We need some bootstrap code similar to what we did in the Codename One Designer tool to support CEF.

Comment: Makes sense. I will patiently wait for this then. Thanks

Comment: I suggest filing an issue and nagging us occasionally. We have a heavy workload and things tend to get lost if people don't follow up enough.

Comment: That's my area of expertise, leave it with me :-)